# Sonarqube has an issue with not closing a returned object. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to fix some of the issues identified by Sonarqube, and I've got several that are all essentially the same as the example shown here. It's telling me I should close the object, but I can't really do that if the object is what the method returns to the caller, can I?

```java
package my.qe.codereview.myservice.data;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import my.qe.review.integration.to.StatusHistoryInsertRequest;

@Component
public class InsertStatusHistoryPSCBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private Properties queryProps;

    public PreparedStatementCreator build(final StatusHistoryInsertRequest request) {
        return new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(queryProps.getProperty("insertStatusHistory"));

                pst.setObject(1, request.getReviewStatusHistoryId());
                pst.setObject(2, request.getReviewHistoryId());

                return pst;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I googled on the issue, and the how-to-fix examples I could find all involved an object that only exists within the scope of the method in question. None addressed the situation where the object is returned by the method as is the case here. I have no control over what the caller does with the object after I return.

What can I do to address this issue? I assume you can't close an object and still return it (is that correct?). Or is the real problem that the method includes a call to another method that can throw an exception, and I need to catch, close, and rethrow?

Update: Using try-with-resources to create the Closeable object didn't work, as the object still gets closed under the covers before the method returns, which results in the caller throwing an exception because the returned object has been closed (which answers the question in the above paragraph). At this time I don't know of a way to return a Closeable object without Sonarqube flagging it as a blocker.

The suggestion was made to mark it as a false positive. I'm not sure if that's an option in my work environment.

Comment: You should just mark it as a false positive and move on.